# How can I pass an Array of RedisFutures to Akka HTTP onSuccess method?

Tags: scala, redis, akka-http

I have a function in my `EmployeesRepository` class with the following signature:

```
def findAllEmployeesById(ids: List[String]): Array[RedisFuture[String]] {...}
```

I am basically trying to pass this to an `EmployeeREST` class which has a `GET` method that takes in a `List[String]` (the employee ids) and is supposed to return a JSON array of corresponding employees retrieved from Redis.

Am I allowed to pass in an `Array[RedisFuture[String]]`? Is there a way for me to actually implement this or am I thinking about it the wrong way? Is there a different way to achieve the functionality I'm trying to implement here?

Comment: You need to post more information the `RedisFuture` type. If it is a subclass of the scala `Future` then you can use `Future.sequence` to create a `RedisFuture[Array[String]]` and pass that to `onComplete`

Comment: I assume you are using lettuce.io, if so `RedisFuture` is a subtype of java future and you can convert it with using the: https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/compat/java8/FutureConverters.scala

Answer (score 2):

Extending some of the comments to the question: you can first convert your `RedisFuture` to a scala `Future` using [the converter](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/compat/java8/FutureConverters.scala):

```
import scala.compat.java8.FutureConverters.toScala

val redisFutureToScalaFuture : RedisFuture[String] => Future[String] = toScala
```

This can be used to convert the entire RedisFuture `Array`:

```
val redisArrayToScala : Array[RedisFuture[String]] => Array[Future[String]] = 
  _ map redisFutureToScalaFuture
```

Now, the `Future.sequence` function will be handy to unwrap the Futures inside of the Array:

```
val unwrapArray : Array[Future[String]] => Future[Array[String]] = Future.sequence
```

Combine all of these together along with the original query function:

```
val idsToFuture : List[String] => Future[Array[String]] = 
  (findAllEmployeesById _) andThen redisArrayToScala andThen unwrapArray
```

Finally, the `idsToFuture` can be used within a [`Directive`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/alphabetically.html):

```
val entityToList : RequestEntity => List[String] = ???

val arrayToResponse : Array[String] => String = ???

val route : Route = 
  get {
    extractRequestEntity { entity =>
      onComplete(idsToFuture(entityToList(entity))) {
        case Success(arr) => complete(200 -> arrayToResponse(arr))
        case Failure(ex)  => complete(500 -> ex.toString)
      }
    }
  }
```